# memcpy vs assignment when copying into an array; why does this generate different code?

Tags: c++, optimization, struct

When compiling the following code,

```
#include <cstring>
struct X { char a, b, c, d; };

void copy_assignment(char* p, X x) {
    *p++ = x.a;
    *p++ = x.b;
    *p++ = x.c;
    *p++ = x.d;
}

void copy_memcpy(char* p, X x) {
    memcpy(p, &x, sizeof(X));
}
```

both GCC and clang emit a a series of movb instructions for `copy_assignment`, while emitting a single movl instruction for `copy_memcpy`.  Assuming `X` has no padding, which it doesn't here, shouldn't the two be equivalent, and isn't a single movl more efficient?

To be precise, I am compiling with:

```
g++ -O3 -S -o prog.S prog.cpp
```

and idem for clang.  GCC version is 7.1.1, Clang version is 4.0.1.  Using -O2, -Os, and -Ofast gives the same result.

Comment: Because a structure is not an array

Comment: Add compilation switches please. And _"...Assuming X has no padding..."_ why assume this?

Comment: Different isn't the same. -- Fred Picker

Comment: No, they really aren't the same even if the outcome is.  In the first example it sees a bunch of pointer incrementing and single byte writes.  In the other it sees it needs to do a write of a specific size and that matches a single `mov` so it chooses that.

Comment: @RichardCritten It is a very easily proven assumption on a concrete implementation if you know the sizeof(X) and number of bits in a char. There's no padding on the given struct here on virtually all the platforms that gcc and clang can target.

Comment: @RichardCritten: The assumption holds on the platform I am comparing on (x86), so the compiler could make use of this fact.

Comment: I think it's simply not implemented. The compilers don't go that far in optimizing.

Comment: Transferring whole words is clearly more efficient than a whole bunch of byte moves. It depends on `memcpy` implementation, but those I've seen in linux kernel on x86 do exactly this, while trying to avoid needless loops. The situation with assignment is more murky. Optimization techniques may differ between releases of the same compiler. But in general a compiler definitely should not act like it's really able to guess what you want it to do.

Comment: One difference is that with `memcpy` the operands are not allowed to overlap, and the compiler knows that (`__builtin_memcpy`). With the first function the compiler itself has to prove that `p` doesn't point to one of the `char` members of `x`. Perhaps it doesn't care to do that? Or saves the effort until the function is inlined?

Comment: Bo makes a good point. Try replacing memcpy with memmove.

Comment: @BoPersson @KlitosKyriacou memmove gives the same result; I doubt proving this should be a problem, since `x` is taken by value.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but for the record `*reinterpret_cast<X*>(p) = x` generates the same code as `memcpy`.

Comment: adding `__restrict` to `copy_assignment` doesn't help either

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not necessarily. As you've said the difference between the compilers and version might stay the same. But looking at the trunk version of gcc the answer is the output is the same as seen [in compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/MSQdy1).